# If A and B are mutually exclusive/disjoint, are A and the compliment of B also mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability

Suppose A and B are mutually exclusive. Then $P(A∪B^{c})=P(A)+P(B^c)$?

Comment: Suppose $B=A^c$.

Comment: So then $P(A\cup B^c)=2\times P(A)$?

Comment: In my example?  No...If $B=A^c$ then $B^c=A$, and $A\cup A=A$.

Comment: Or suppose that $B$ is empty and $P(A)>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $A$ is a subset of $B^c$.

Comment: So how would that be used to find $P(A\cup B^c)$ or $P(A\cap B^c)$?

Comment: If one set is a subset of another, think about what the union of those two sets would be.  A Venn diagram might help.  (Similarly for the intersection of the sets.)

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me visualize it. So $P(A\cup B^c)=P(B^c)$ and $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)$

Comment: You're welcome!  P.S. It is customary to upvote and/or accept an answer you find helpful.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote unfortunately.

Comment: @MohammedShahid For acceptance no reputation is needed, I will do the upvoting for you.

Comment: @Vera I didn't realize that. Just accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ & $B$ are mutually exclusive then $ A\subseteq B^c$.

Hence $A\cup B^c =B^c$ $\Rightarrow \mathbb{P} (A\cup B^c)=\mathbb{P} (B^c)$.